# Struggling with finding the closest occurence of character in string

Tags: java, data-structures

I am trying to find the closes duplicate occurrence of a character in the string but I am stuck and not sure how to proceed.

Question is something like, example:

String s = "babab" with index given as 2, find closest occurrence of that character. so 0 and 4 here, with 0 being closest to 2.

What I have so far,

```
public static List<Integer> closest(String s, List<Integer> queries) {
    // Write your code here
        int min;
        int count = 0;
        List<Integer> ans = new List<Integer>();
        for(int i=0; i<queries.size(); i++){
            char a = s.charAt(i);
            for(int j=0; j<s.length(); j++){
                if(s[j] == a ){
                    int count = j;
                }else{
                    count = -1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood the problem correctly, but here is a potential solution. Note that this program has O(n*m) complexity where m=number of queries and n=length of string. This can be further optimized.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

public static List<Integer> closest(String s, List<Integer> queries) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    //execute each query separately
    for(int i=0; i<queries.size(); i++){
        char target = s.charAt(queries.get(i));
        int index = queries.get(i);
        int length = s.length();

        int currentStep = 1;
        boolean founded = false;
        //search for the closest character
        while(index-currentStep>=0 || index+currentStep<length){
            if(index-currentStep>=0 && s.charAt(index-currentStep)==target){
                result.add(index-currentStep);
                founded = true;
                break;
            }else if(index+currentStep<length && s.charAt(index+currentStep)==target){
                result.add(index+currentStep);
                founded = true;
                break;
            }
            currentStep++;
        }
        if(!founded){
            //we couldn't find the element
            result.add(-1);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "babab";
    List<Integer> queries = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    queries.add(2);

    List<Integer> result = closest(s,queries);
    for(Integer res: result){
        System.out.println(res);
    }
}

}
```

**Update:** Here is a solution with the complexity O(max(n,m)). Let me analyize the complexity a bit. First, this problem cannot be solved in less than O(n) because we have to access each character at least once. Additionally, for each query we have at least one access with any algorithm so it requires at least m steps (if we run the algorithm in parallel with m workers, the complexity would be O(n)). Now the solution: We build a couple of data structures that will help us (in prepareDb). This process takes 3*n, it can be optimized a bit, but this still gives O(n). Then, we simply query the array that contains the index of the closest element which takes m steps for m queries (O(m)). Finally, this gives O(n)+O(m), or O(max(n,m)) in total. Here is the solution:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

public static List<Integer> prepareDb(String s) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();

    //fron similar
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> dbFront = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<Character, Integer> lastSeenFront= new HashMap<>();
    for(int i = 0; i<s.length();i++){
        Character c = s.charAt(i);
        int distance = -1;
        if(lastSeenFront.containsKey(c)){
            distance = i - lastSeenFront.get(c);
        }
        lastSeenFront.put(c,i);
        dbFront.put(i, distance);
    }

    //backSimilar
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> dbBack = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<Character, Integer> lastSeenBack = new HashMap<>();
    for(int i = s.length()-1; i >= 0;i--){
        Character c = s.charAt(i);
        int distance = -1;
        if(lastSeenBack.containsKey(c)){
            distance = lastSeenBack.get(c) - i;
        }
        lastSeenBack.put(c,i);
        dbBack.put(i, distance);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<s.length();i++){
        //distance between i and the closest element
        int distance = dbFront.get(i);
        if(dbFront.get(i)==-1 || (dbBack.get(i)!=-1 && dbFront.get(i)>dbBack.get(i))){
            distance = dbBack.get(i);
        }
        result.add(distance);
    }
    return result;
}


public static List<Integer> closest(String s, List<Integer> queries) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    List<Integer> db = prepareDb(s);

    //execute each query separately
    for(int i=0; i<queries.size(); i++){
        result.add(db.get(queries.get(i)));
    }
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "babab";
    List<Integer> queries = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    queries.add(2);

    List<Integer> result = closest(s,queries);
    for(Integer res: result){
        System.out.println(res);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: This works fine but the runtime is still greather than what I expected. I need to do it in O(n)

Comment: @Pulkit I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

If i understood the problem you can do this in O(n) time.

Algo: input(String s, int idx)

1. Create a list which stores all the indexes of occurrences of that particular character except idx itself.
2. Initialize min_difference = Integer.MAX_VALUE and closestIndex = -1.
3. Iterate through the list and calculate the mod difference of the index in the list with the idx while maintaining the min_difference and closestIndex.

For eg. for string "babab" and idx = 2 then:

After executing first step the list we created is {0, 4}

In step 3 we do |2 - 0| = 2 (update min_difference = 2, closestIndex = 0) and |2 - 4| = 2 (at this point it depends on your requirement whether you want any closestIndex. It is your choice to update or not).

Answer (score 0):

## String API soltion

The string API actually can help you make this whole thing a lot easier.

You can use [indexOf(int, int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int,%20int)) to find the next use of the char. You can use [substring(int,int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) to only look in part of the String. And you can use [lastIndexOf(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(int)) to find the very last occurrence of a char.

Using these methods your search method per string would look something like this

```
public static int closest(String s, int index) {
    char target = s.charAt(index);
    int next = s.indexOf(target, index+1);
    int previous = s.substring(0, index).lastIndexOf(target);
    //The below code probably needs so work to handle not found case (ie -1)
    if (index-previous <= next-index) {
        return previous;
    } else {
        return next;
    }
}
```

You can then use this in your previous function:

```
public static List<Integer> closest(String s, List<Integer> queries) {
    queries.stream().mapToInt(I -> closets(s,i)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```